# Is there a null(empty) value in Numeric in labview?

Tags: labview

I would like to enter empty in place of Zero in numeric. i dont want use strings.
In Numeric field we can enter only NAN or INF but i want enter Empty.

Comment: There isn't an empty value for a numeric datatype, so if you really need this you'd probably have to implement something using variants or classes. What are you trying to do and why isn't `NaN` suitable for your needs though? Can you show some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an Empty value for floating-point numerics in LabVIEW, just as there is no such thing in C#, C++, Java, or C. They all use the same IEEE standard to define floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an idea for this on the Idea Exchange: [Create an "Optional" input type wrapper in the style of C++17's std::optional](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW-Idea-Exchange/Create-an-quot-Optional-quot-input-type-wrapper-in-the-style-of/idi-p/3733023).

It was largely rejected because it's not a suitably useful thing for general use, but some ideas as to how you might implement it yourself were discussed there (don't miss the second page).